# Cannot upgrade packages using pip inside virtualenv

Tags: python, tensorflow, virtualenv

I wanted to be able to access all of my site packages from another installation of Python, so I created a virtual environment in this way:

```
venv my_project --system-site-packages
```

I noticed that my version of Keras was outdated, so from within my virtualenv, I executed:

```
pip install keras
```

which worked without an issue. I'm using pip version 9.0.1

I'm trying to run a python program that uses TensorFlow, but when I run it, I get an error:

```
ImportError: No module named tensorboard.plugins
```

I googled around and found that I needed to upgrade TensorFlow. I tried several commands:

```
(my_project/) user@GPU5:~/spatial/zero_padded/powerlaw$ pip install tensorflow
```

The above gives me a 'requirement already satisfied' error.

```
$ pip install --target=~/spatial/zero_padded/powerlaw/my_project/ --upgrade tensorflow
Collecting tensorflow
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

The output of `which python`:

```
/user/spatial/zero_padded/powerlaw/my_project/bin/python
```

I think my `PYTHONPATH` is the first line in this:

```
(my_project/) user@GPU5:~/spatial/zero_padded/powerlaw/my_project$ python -c "import sys; print '\n'.join(sys.path)"

/user/spatial/zero_padded/powerlaw/my_project
/opt/enthought/canopy-1.5.1/appdata/canopy-1.5.1.2730.rh5-x86_64/lib/python27.zip
/opt/enthought/canopy-1.5.1/appdata/canopy-1.5.1.2730.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7
/opt/enthought/canopy-1.5.1/appdata/canopy-1.5.1.2730.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2
/opt/enthought/canopy-1.5.1/appdata/canopy-1.5.1.2730.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/opt/enthought/canopy-1.5.1/appdata/canopy-1.5.1.2730.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/opt/enthought/canopy-1.5.1/appdata/canopy-1.5.1.2730.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/user/spatial/zero_padded/powerlaw/my_project/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/user/pkgs/enthought/canopy-1.5.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/user/pkgs/enthought/canopy-1.5.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL
/opt/enthought/canopy-1.5.1/appdata/canopy-1.5.1.2730.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

How do I upgrade TensorFlow inside my virtualenv?

Comment: Can you please post the output of `pip --freeze | grep -i tensorflow` from inside your virtualenv?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure that all you need to do is run `pip install` with `-U` to upgrade the package inside the virtualenv:

```
(my_project/) user@GPU5:~/spatial/zero_padded/powerlaw$ pip install -U tensorflow
```

`-U` is just shorthand for `--upgrade`.  But, you should really go ahead and create a dependencies file for yourself called `requirements.txt` that lives in the project root and specify version numbers there.

e.g.,

```
tensorflow==1.2.0
```

And that makes it easier to install all requirements

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: I tried this, and it still upgraded everywhere - that is, globally - instead of locally to (my_project/)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it is install the dependencies outside de vm, and create a new one I'm afraid to say that. Because doing upgrades is different than installing

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but can you be more specific? What exactly do I need to do?